# Why does reshape work differently for Transpose and return a new nd array?

Tags: python, numpy, view, numpy-ndarray

Why does `reshape` return a new array when transposed and return view when not transposed? When does it return views and when a new array?

```
a = np.zeros((3,2)) 
b = a.T.reshape(3*2) 
c = a.reshape(3*2) 
print(a)

c[2] = 10000 
b[0] = 10000 
print(a)

print(b)
```

**Result**

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]

[[    0.     0.]
 [10000.     0.]
 [    0.     0.]]

[10000.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
```

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), it's a view *if possible*: *"It is not always possible to change the shape of an array without copying the data. If you want an error to be raised when the data is copied, you should assign the new shape to the shape attribute of the array"*.

Comment: its not clear .Can you demonstrate an example?

Comment: Start with `a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)`.  Compare `a.ravel(order='C")` and `a.T.ravel(order='C')`.  See how the `a.T` has reordered the underlying elements?  It's that reordering that requires a copy.